# Best way to provide validation to spring mvc & hibernate projects

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring & hibernate, please suggest a best way to provide validation to spring mvc & hibernate projects. I tried hibernate validator but i don't know how to use it when there is relationship(like @OneToOne) between entity objects. If there is any examples, please provide the link.

Comment: what sort of validations are you expecting on @OneToOne Relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Your @OneToOne relationship is not clear enough. Could you please give a concrete scenario?

In Spring MVC you have three types of validations:

- JSR-303 bean validation (hibernate validator)
- Custom validation
- Spring validation

JSR-303 works great for simple validations on single fields. You have standard annotations like (@Max, @Min, @NULL, @Pattern, etc.). It does not seem enough for you in this case.

Custom validation is used in a more complex scenario. For instance, what if we need to validate that the newly added product ID is not the same as any of the existing product IDs?

Spring validation represents cross-field validation.
For instance, it's used when we want to compare two or more fields to see if
their values can be considered as valid when combined.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use spring validation method.
using valid annotion in controller classes infront of modelattribute  annotaion.
then you can use validaions in the model class.

below is an example for controller and bean classes.

this is a many to one configuration inside a bean class:

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserType.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_type", referencedColumnName = "id")
@NotNull
private UserType userTypeTb;

this is a method inside controller class with valid and modelattribute annotaion:

public ModelAndView home(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user,  BindingResult result,
  HttpServletRequest request) {
//
//
}
```